# Are there new items in The Zodiac Age?

Tags: ps4, final-fantasy-12

I've noticed that I am picking up items that I have never seen before in the original game. I've received quite a few "Prince's Kiss" items, which remove sleep from a character, but I seem to remember that an "Alarm Clock" was used in the original.

What other new items have been added to the PS4 remaster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, but I cannot tell clearly if these items and name changes came with The Zodiac Age or the earlier Japan only International Zodiac Job System release.

I cannot produce an exhaustive list of changes between the PS2 and the Zodiac Age PS4 release, but there are other facts to keep in mind when comparing these two games.

In Japan, around one year after the release of the original FF 12, they received an updated/reworked version of FF 12 called the **International Zodiac Job System**, or **IZJS** for short.

This Japan-only release featured many changes to the game, among these were new items and equipment and changes to existing items.

[Here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/939426-final-fantasy-xii-international-zodiac-job-system/faqs/49691) is an extensive GamesFAQ entry that shows differences in the original and **IZJS** release. I cannot find for sure if there were any item renames done then already, the *Alarm Clock* mentioned by you is still being listed in this GameFAQ entry, but no *Prince's Kiss*. The [Final Fantasy Wikia entry for Alarm Clock](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Alarm_Clock) lists it being renamed to Prince's Kiss in the *Zodiac* versions. I cannot tell if this means the **IZJS** release or **The Zodiac Age**.

The changes made in **IZJS** are included in **The Zodiac Age**, including the changes and additions that the new game itself brings to FF 12.

According to the [differences page in the Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XII/Version_differences), there do not seem to be any additional items in this release but the game was balanced to be easier, so this might include changed item drops and changed availability in shops.

I hope this info helps to understand the differences in the three games.

Edit: [Brandon Zappy's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/313581/192395) has a link for a useful item comparison I did not find on the wikia. I should focus less on work and more on my answer research it seems ;).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article from IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-xii/New_Features_and_Differences_in_Final_Fantasy_XII:_The_Zodiac_Age) there have new weapons and armor, among other things, but no mention of any new items. I didn't remember a "Prince's Kiss" item from the original game either, so I continued doing some research until I found [this very helpful wiki article](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XII_items) (Really though, what wiki isn't helpful) that show's all the new items that have been added in each category. The items are in a column where the header will either state "FFXII" or "Zodiac" with Zodiac being the new release. Hope this helps!